# Is there a modern single-seat turboprop?

Tags: turboprop

There seem to be a number of tandem seat turboprop trainers like the PC-9/Texan and the Super Tucano. Are there any single-seat turboprops? I am asking about modern production planes.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Although most aircraft to find good use for a turboprop need to have more than one seat, some single-seat uses do exist. For example, agricultural aircraft like the [Air Tractor AT-802](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Tractor_AT-802), [Thrush models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayres_Thrush), and the [PZL-106 Kruk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PZL-106_Kruk) are all currently in production.